# chrome 18 ignores my osx font rendering settings

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, fonts

I'm my mac I set all fonts below say 16px to have font smoothing disabled. chrome obeyed that as well.

yesterday it updated itself to version 18 and now it is the only software that ignores that settings and smooth all fonts which makes my eyes bleed...

how can I politely ask chrome to stick to my settings ?

Macbook pro 15", OSX Lion 10.7.3

thank

Answer (score 0):

This is a "known issue" over on Google Groups for Chrome:

https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/8EsWzmoxp40/rzas0ZLEHfkJ

Comment: this might be related, but the post in google groups talk about weird characters and not aliasing issues